# PDF javascript viewer with digital signature

Tags: javascript, pdf

I've been looking for a javascript library to view PDF files with digital signatures, I tried many libraries but still none of them could view the signature. Is there any library for that, even in beta?

Comment: What do you mean by "view the signature"? Are you merely missing an existing in-document pdf signature visualisation? Or are you looking for an extra signature panel?

Comment: I mean the visualization part, the file is viewed but no signature is shown

Comment: Signature visualizations are normal annotations. Thus, any annotation aware library should do.

Comment: ... assuming the signature annotation has an appearance. It might not.

Comment: @JoelGeraci If it has no appearance, it likely is an invisible signature anyways. Thus, not showing anything would be correct as far as in-document visualizations are concerned. ;)